# Що робити, коли тобі не подобаються зміни до твоєї відповіді/питання?

Tags: discussion

Чи правильно натискати rollback?.. Чи треба терпіти? :)
Питання виникло, бо декілька людей схвалили зміни + одна людина їх запропонувала. З іншого боку, я вважаю нову версію відповіді менш ясною - там додалося те, що я не хотів би писати. Припустімо навіть, що там з'явилася хибна з моєї точки зору інформація.

Думка цікавить про загальний випадок, а не про конкретний, але щоб був приклад, питання виникло через [це редагування](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/236).

P.S. Раптом хтось дочитав, це буде вже про цей конкретний випадок: @s0nata, @bytebuster, прошу уважно читати зміни. По-перше там одрук "викорстовує**с**ться", по-друге, хіба слово "запитати" має значення "порушити питання"?..

Comment: Маєте рацію. Не вчитався, прошу пробачення.

Comment: Щодо одруку у зміненому, приймають зміни та виправляють одруки, або зайве. Або відхиляють зміни (істотні, але зайві), та виправляють якісь очевидні огріхи(незначні) власноруч.
Перепрошую за небажані зміни. :)
Зараз подивлюсь, що там з приводу "порушити питання"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Кому належить останнє слово

Я вважаю, що людина абсолютно вправі відкотити будь-які зміни в її відповіді. І авторитет/кількість тих, хто підтримує зміну, тут, як на мене, ні до чого. Це Ваша відповідь (а не вікі-відповідь). Якщо когось не влаштовує зміст чиєїсь відповіді, її можуть мінусувати чи закривати, але останнє рішення про зміни, по-моєму, завжди залишається за автором.

## Не міняйте зміст

Щодо конкретно цієї зміни — то я голосував проти неї ще давним давно. З однієї простої причини — вона **змінює зміст** відповіді (а не є незначним виправленням); лише цього одного достатньо, щоб відхилилити її на етапі прийняття (навіть якщо автор згоден). Про зміни суті, по-моєму, треба просити в коментарях.

> #### [What should I *not* do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120583/252301)
>
> When you edit other's posts, you're still editing *their* content. Therefore you should never …
>
> - Change the meaning of the original post.

## My personal opinion about editing in SE

SE provides an “edit” button to give the users a feel of wiki, but doesn't fully behave as wiki. Wiki is a website that provides collaborative modification of its content. SE provides collaborative modification of decor and of wiki-answers — but not more.

Comment: Дякую, посилання на meta.stackexchange.com завжди заспокоюють. Дякую, я бачив, що ви голосували проти ) Цікаво почути думку тих, хто голосував за.

Comment: Так само вважав що зміни розпивають коротку і зрозумілу відповідь, але очікував що автор сам поставить останню крапку у доречності такого редагування. Натиснув Skip.